# Need Python Code For LSM6DSOX Accelerometer with Raspberry Pi 3b+

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, accelerometer, motion-detection

Im trying to figure out some python code that essentially will detect movement/motion of the LSM6DSOX Accelerometer and will further execute code to activate an raspberry pi camera to take a picture once movement is detected.

```
        import time import board from adafruit_lsm6ds.lsm6dsox

        import LSM6DSOX sensor = LSM6DSOX(i2c)

        camera = PiCamera()

        accel_x,accel_y,accel_z = sensor.acceleration

        class Watcher: 
    
        def __init__(self, value):        
       
        self.variable = value 

        def set_value(self, new_value):         
          
        if self.variable != new_value: 
            
        self.post_change()

        def post_change(self):         

        camera.capture("/home/pi/Pictures/img.jpg")     
    
        print("Done.")  
    
        time.sleep(2) def main(): 

        def main():
    
        Watcher.setValue(self,accel_x)
```

Comment: What were your attempts? What errors did you find in your attempts? You need to publish them.

Comment: This is what I've tried so far, no errors but, the issue im running into is that when I move my accelerometer it doesnt activate the raspberry pi camera like I would like it to. Essentially am confused on how to code the detection of movement in my accelerometer. Not very familiar with python but, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add the information in your question using ```Edit```, with the correct formatting for codes. That way people can visualize the problem and help you.

Comment: Sorry new to stack overflow. Used the ` ` but seems to not space out the way I want it to. Any way to fix this @Digital Farmer

Comment: Hi @Lemickey, no problem → Edit the question itself and add this code data to it, there you can modify and see the final result before being published!